# What did you do [today] in order to improve your English [today]?

Tags: word-order

Where to put the word 'today' in this sentence?

> A. What did you do **today** in order to improve your English?
>
> B. What did you do in order to improve your English **today**?

By my teachers in past I was told to put the 'time denoting words' always in the end, but in this sentence it seems to have two meanings if I'll put it in the end.

1st meaning:  the question is about today's doing. 
2nd meaning: the question is about today's English.

Answer (score 1):

They are both perfectly fine.

However, I would prefer the first variant, because **today** sits close to the word it clarifies, **do**.

If **today** sits next to **English**, the listener must do an extra (slight) effort to match **today** with **do**.

Additionally, in the second sentence, I would add some commas:

> B. What did you do, in order to improve your English, today?

Comment: virolino, I don't think the commas are appropriate. The pair of commas make the parenthetical non-essential or non-restrictive. And without the parenthetical, the sentence does not quite hold the same meaning, which it should if the part enclosed in commas was a real parenthetical (additional but non-essential information). Also, the sentence is very straightforward and short. There is no need for the commas.

Comment: `And without the parenthetical, the sentence does not quite hold the same meaning` - that is not the point, to hold the meaning. The decision to use commas or not is made on having any meaning or not. Of course, if information is removed, the meaning is no longer as rich.